# File Download from remote server

Tags: asp.net, download

I am facing a strange problem.

I have a web page(Filelibrary.aspx) to download some word/pdf files, I can download the files from local machine and direct link from my local pc. but we have a server and we are usualy accessing the site by login into the server as remote desktop. If we try to download word/pdf files from remort desk top it is downloading the web page "Filelibrary.aspx" instead of the word/pdf. we are using https. I could able to download it before when it was http.

my code:

```
String strFile = String.Empty;
String[] filename;

strFile = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TemplatePath"].ToString()) + FileName;

filename = strFile.Split('\\');

Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;// Read the original file from diskFileStream *
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename[filename.Length-1]);

String ext = String.Empty;
if (strFile.IndexOf(".") > 0)
    ext = (strFile.Split('.'))[1];
if (ext.ToLower() == "txt")
    Response.ContentType = "text/html";
if (ext.ToLower() == "xls")
    Response.ContentType = "xls/html";
if (ext.ToLower() == "pdf")
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 

////combine the path and file name
if (File.Exists(strFile))//open the file and process it
{
    FileStream sourceFile = new FileStream(strFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    long FileSize;
    FileSize = sourceFile.Length;
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", FileSize.ToString()); //*
    byte[] getContent = new byte[(int)FileSize];
    sourceFile.Read(getContent, 0, (int)FileSize);

    sourceFile.Close();
    Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);
}
Common.UserPageAudit(Session["User"].ToString(), "Download Templates", Session["ROLE"].ToString(), strFile + " Template downloaded");
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this strange issue..?

Comment: From the server, is it downloading the actual source file `Filelibrary.aspx`, or is it downloading the Word/PDF file, but it is being saved as `Filelibrary.aspx`?

Comment: No it is exactly downloads the html content. and when we tried to open in word it is showing error of loading css files

Comment: then it sounds like your server is not executing the aspx file, but rather serving it as a static file. Check whether ASP.Net is installed on the server and correctly registered in IIS (I assume, IIS)

Comment: I tried to download using Google Chrome it is working  fine.. all others can only use IE becasue of their security policy.. is there any security settings in IE to restrinct the File download while user is in remote login ?

Comment: It may be because IE is operating in quirks mode, or because the rendering engine is not set to the latest. Are you setting `X-UA-Compatible` to edge and do you have a valid doctype? I'm grasping at straws here though. Maybe if you add in some more info walking through the different scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you friends...
at last I found the Problem.
I was not clearing the Header.. I have changed my code as below.

```
            String strFile = String.Empty;
        String[] filename;

        strFile = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TemplatePath"].ToString()) + FileName;

        filename = strFile.Split('\\');
```

// Added these two line
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();

```
        Response.ClearHeaders();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;// Read the original file from diskFileStream *
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename[filename.Length-1]);


        String ext = String.Empty;
        if (strFile.IndexOf(".") > 0)
            ext = (strFile.Split('.'))[1];

        if (ext.ToLower() == "txt")
            Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        if (ext.ToLower() == "xls")
            Response.ContentType = "xls/html";
        if (ext.ToLower() == "pdf")
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 

        ////combine the path and file name
        if (File.Exists(strFile))//open the file and process it
        {
            FileStream sourceFile = new FileStream(strFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            long FileSize;
            FileSize = sourceFile.Length;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", FileSize.ToString()); //*
            byte[] getContent = new byte[(int)FileSize];
            sourceFile.Read(getContent, 0, (int)FileSize);

            sourceFile.Close();
            Response.BinaryWrite(getContent);
        }
        Common.UserPageAudit(Session["User"].ToString(), "Download Templates", Session["ROLE"].ToString(), strFile + " Template downloaded");
```